# html a tag to trigger an action

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In my current Net Core MVC project i would like to do the following:
How can I get an `<a>` element to trigger some action in my controller, send some value, and then return the same page?

What I have:
View:

```
<a asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-route-id="@item.ID"><i class="far fa-check-square" ></i></a>
```

This need to trigger a method in my Controller, but all it does is open a new, white page (following the routing: "`.../ControllerName/ConcludeAct/item.ID`").

My controller `ControllerName` looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConcludeAct(int id, string value)
{
    // do logic
    return redirect("/somepage");  
}
```

So a click on the  element should trigger this method, send the `int id` and `string value` do some processing and then return the view.
Both `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` do not work, it still routes to the empty page.

If this is not possible with an `<a>` element, what element can I best use, where I can also use the icon from FontAwsome?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
<a asp-controller="ControllerName" asp-route-id="@item.ID" asp-action="ConcludeAct" asp-route-value="nextStage" type="button"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></a>
```